# avoid null or undefined for 'empty' variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I saw this code

```
    recipient(message) {
      return users.find(u => u.id === message.recipient) || null;
    }
```

it make me wonder why the author have fallback using `null`, what's the problem leaving out the fallback?

Comment: Note: this code also defeats finding any value in the array that happens to be falsey such as `0` or an empty string because it will override the found falsey value and return `null`.  Perhaps OK here because `u.id` won't be falsey, but problematic in general.

Answer (score 0):

Because `find` by default returns `undefined` if not item is found - this is returned by user-defined in a variety of ways as well. `null` is used as a signal indicating that the item was not found, but a value was returned.

Alternatively, you could return an empty object:

```
return users.find(({ id }) => id === message.recipient) || {};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return users.find(u => u.id === message.recipient)
```

`find` returns undefined in case no value is found, so if your logic where the return value is used just check for `null` or need `null` to be default value in case no value is found, so this clearly depend how you logic which use returned value